# SharePoint Stack Exchange Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 730 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- SharePoint Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- SharePoint Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: sharepoint.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: sharepoint.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Woohoo! I'm looking forward to the goodies. Not too sure about that sticker though... :P

Comment: really good surprise, thank you :)

Comment: I'll have to negotiate with my wife to be granted the right to wear it :p

Comment: Wow !! My first surprise on 2012. Thanks v.much. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the nice surprise Rebecca. Looking forward to it!

Comment: @KitMenke It's a key to SharePoint knowledge! What else could it be???

Comment: What a great surprise! Going to wear it at the Arctic SharePoint Challenge and Norwegian Developer Conference to spread the love!

Comment: ...Seems that I have somehow managed to slip in the list too (bottom second page)! I suppose I was lucky ^_^'. 
@KitMenke: I suppose I could use the sticker to complete my "Cardboard shield of SharePoint protection +1" :P, need to doublecheck the AR bonus of a coton t-shirt on my "SharePoint Rpg" manual...

Comment: Great stuff! I've been sporting a sticker I got from Alex Angas (I think), but having a spare will be good insurance.

Comment: can't wait to proudly wear my geek pride :P

Comment: Thanks! Great to be able to contribute to the community :)

Comment: Awesome, can't wait to unbox it :-)

Comment: Just asking - anyway one can confirm if he should have received the aforementioned mail? Who can I contact to confirm this? Thank you.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist we just got the swag made from our printshop. we're shipping the packages to top users this week.

Comment: @Jin: the problem is that I never received the mail at all, so I was asking if I can contact someone to confirm if I was in the top user list when the swag was first planned. Or are you telling me that you suspended sending the e-mail to wait for the printshop to complete the order?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I thought the same thing then realized that the email addy I use for StackExchange is one I seldom check.  I just checked and the email was there

Comment: @DaveWise - I check that mail every day. If the mails were sent for all the top user, there are only two possible outcome: a) the list of top user was generated before I reached 730rep (don't think so, if my memory doesn't play tricks on me I was around 780-800) or b) the mail was blocked somewhere along the way. I was trying to determine if it is A or B.

Comment: I never received my swag package :(

Answer (score 2):

Just received mail that I am one of the top users... I really appreciate that we get that package, cool! Hope it arrives on time, to show off the stuff on the Dutch techdays!

Comment: Received the email also, totally awesome!

Answer (score 2):

W00t

I've found my outfit to the Dutch TechDays :)

Comment: when is Dutch TechDays?

Comment: 16&17 feb 2012 (http://www.techdays.nl/)

Comment: make sure to come by and check my session! ;) You can recognize me by my SP Stackexchange shirt ;)

Answer (score 1):

are the goodies still available? I would love to get my hands on the T-Shirt and the stickers.

Comment: I belive that was a one-time prize. That said, I never understood if I was included and should have received that mail of else. Anyway, it's pretty strange... seems that the shop site doesn't even exist no more O_o

Comment: Yeah even if the offer is not still going on, I would love to buy the T-Shirt and the stickers. But yes the shop site doesn't seem to exist any more.

Comment: K, checked, I would say that the shop is [officially dead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140882/shop-link-still-present-on-so-and-meta).

Comment: That said, since the shop is now dead, I guess no one will get angry if we print our version of the T-shirt right?