# Top interesting questions for the site cards

Tags: discussion, design, business-cards

I'm in the process of creating generic site cards for SharePoint StackExchange community. I'd like to pick 3 interesting questions be featured on the one side (individually).

The idea is that when we pass out these cards to people, the questions are so interesting that they'd be inclined to get on the computer and type in the URL to find out the answer.

I prefer to have the 3 questions to cover different scopes of the site. All should have accepted answers. It'd be great if the question is in the "How to ... ?" or "What ... ?" format.

Below is a mockup

[image: site minicards]

Once we have the cards made and mailed to our HQ, I'll create a follow up post with instructions on how to obtain these cards. These cards will be available for anyone who request them. Depending on how fast they can be made, I'll try to include them in our top user [swag packages](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/sharepoint-stack-exchange-top-user-swag).

Comment: I think we should try to get 3 questions that appeal to the various SharePoint audiences: developer, admin, and end-user.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple questions I found interesting browsing around. Like I said in my comment above, I think we should try to hit the various roles people have: developer, admin, and end-user.

Developer questions:

- [When to use OpenWeb() vs RootWeb?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/17740/2070) - There are any number of SPWeb questions we could use that are good.
- [How do you get the current list item in JavaScript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/11169/2070) - Pretty involved but interesting.
- [Is it necessary to call SPWeb.Update() after setting AllowUnsafeUpdates?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/12675/2070) - Question by @GraceNote and answer by me.. is this cheating to nominate myself? ;)

Admin questions:

- [jQuery accordion for the Quick Launch menu?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/18442/2070) - Gotta have jQuery somewhere!
- [Sorting grouped items in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/27458/2070) - Such an annoying problem but the answer is so simple!

End user

- [Why doesn't clicking New Document save back to the document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/13884/2070)
- [How do I check in a LOT of files all at once?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/12214/2070)

Comment: These are great Kit. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! We have tons of great questions so hopefully we can get more from other people. :)